# upsert and delete in delta table in spark streaming

Tags: pyspark, merge, spark-streaming, upsert, delta-lake

I am a bit new to structured streaming. If you can help me out, it would be great. Thanks in advance.

I have a batch file (suppose csv) which we are converting to 1 event per record and sending it to Azure event hub (same as Kafka topics). We are reading it, doing some data quality check and storing to delta table. But **before storing into delta table we need to do upsert and delete based on a column which says the state as: updated, created or deleted.** And based on that we need to merge the record based on a key into delta table (what I mean is to upsert or delete the records). Can you please tell me the *best way to do it while streaming*?

Comment: If you are using databricks [this](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/merge-in-streaming.html) could be helpful

Comment: Did you check the Azure Stream Analytics-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/stream-data-stream-analytics-integration?view=azuresql

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation. Update the silver table with the new data present in the bronze table. I opened a discussion on the databricks forum.

https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D58Y000096U4yASAS